# Ada Text_IO Put printing out after Get

Tags: ada

I am trying to get a character input from the user in this format:

```
Player 1: a
```

This is my code:

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put("Player"&Integer'Image(board.turn)&": ");
Ada.Text_IO.Get(Item => move);
```

Now, when I run my program this is what happens:

```
a
Player 1:
```

For some odd reason, the GET is appearing before the PUT... I tried flipping their positions and it still occurs the same way.

I recently upgraded my AdaCore GNAT from 2012 to 2014 and I didn't have this issue in 2012...

Am I missing something?

Please help!

These are my with/use if you need them:

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Characters.Handling;
with Ada.Exceptions; use Ada.Exceptions;
USE Ada, Ada.Text_Io;
```

**NEW**

Here is more code... Don't worry about the AI stuff...

Full code:

```
PROCEDURE Main IS
  PACKAGE board is new connectfour;
  USE board;
begin
  PUT("   ********** CONNECT-FOUR *********"); Put_Line("");
  AI.start;
  while (not board.isFull) loop
    if AIwin = true then goto Win; end if;
    Put_Line(""); DELAY 0.5;
    Put("Player"&Integer'Image(board.turn)&": ");
    Get(move);
    if move='0' then goto Quit; end if;
    Put_Line("");
    if board.Move(move) = true then goto Win; end if;
    board.print; DELAY 0.5;
    AI.print;
  end loop;
  <<Win>>
  Put_Line("");
  Put_Line("PLAYER"&Integer'Image(board.turn)&" IS THE WINNER!");

  <<Quit>>
  AI.stop;
  Put_Line("");
  if move='0' then
    Put_Line("PLAYER"&Integer'Image(board.turn)&" HAS FORFEIT!");
    if board.turn = 1 then
      Put_Line("PLAYER 2 IS THE WINNER!");
    else
      Put_Line("PLAYER 1 IS THE WINNER BY DEFAULT!");
    end if;
  end if;
end Main;
```

Answer (score 3):

The standard output may be being buffered. Try

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put("Player"&Integer'Image(board.turn)&": “);
Ada.Text_IO.Flush;
Ada.Text_IO.Get(Item => move);
```

(later)

Well, that wasn’t the answer. I just tried

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Borovez is
   Move : Character;
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put ("Player" & Integer'Image (42) & ": ");
   --  Ada.Text_IO.Flush;
   Ada.Text_IO.Get (Item => Move);
end Borovez;
```

on GNAT GPL 2014/Windows 7 and it worked exactly as expected.

You’re going to need to edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is probably right, but I'm wondering why the standard output is being buffered... that isn't normal, is it?  The text comes out in the right order when I try it.  Is it possible that previous input might be interfering?

Comment: No that did not fix the issue :/ Still does the same thing

Comment: Oh. What OS are you using? (as @ajb says, your code works for me - Mac OS X).

Comment: Im using windows... with AdaCore GNAT 2014... its still not working correctly

Comment: I still need help please!

Comment: @Borovez: Actually *less* code would be more helpful, specifically a *minimal* and *complete* sample program that reproduces the problem (without any of the "AI stuff"). I just wrote a 7-line program that *might* be what you need to include in your question: http://codepad.org/N094eNGu -- if that reproduces the error on your system (it doesn't on mine), feel free to copy it into your question.

Comment: Yea im doing it exactly how I am supposed to... and it is still not doing it correctly...  have any other ideas?

Comment: @Borovez: Yes, I already gave you an idea. Did you try the program I posted at http://codepad.org/N094eNGu? Did it exhibit the problem? Telling us you're doing it exactly how you're supposed to is not helpful; I don't know what that means (other than that you *think* you're doing everything right).

Comment: I can confirm that Simon's `procedure Borovez` works exactly as requested on a Debian/GNU Linux system; the message `Player 42: ` shows up before I enter a character.

Comment: yes I mean I am doing everything correctly, like in your example. Are you sure you guys tested your program in ADACORE 2014?

Comment: Yes (GNAT GPL 2014 on Mac OS X).